# How to Implement iBeacon functionality in iOS 7

Tags: ios7, core-bluetooth, ibeacon

Please anybody let me know how to implement iBeacon functionality in iOS 7.
I need to search how many Bluetooth devices are available in my circle or region.
Please help me how to achieve this.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

What Rob said.

The sample app is called AirLocate. If you follow Rob's link, you then have to open the 2013 WWDC sample apps link. Then search on "airLocate"

Comment: Is there any way to change the Major and minor Id values programatically?Please let me know.

Comment: Thank you for the reply. I get the solution and implemented according your suggestion.

Comment: Laxmi, the major and minor numbers are hard-coded into AirLocate. (It has a list of 3 you can choose from.) I just released to the store a full-featured iBeacon test app called BeaconTest that I developed for my company. It lets you manage a list of UUIDs, enter UUIDs from the keyboard, generate them programmatically, and send them to other devices using AirDrop, Messages, or email. It also has the option to disable device sleep when it's transmitting, and lots of other useful features. Try it at http://tinyurl.com/beacontest

Answer (score 0):

First thing to do is go watch the WWDC session from 2013: What's New in Core Location. That has a discussion of beacons and regions. Then download the sample code. If you don't have any beacons, you can use an iOS device as a beacon (old phone, iPad, etc.).

The example code will show you how you can find the beacon, based on its UDID. To count the beacons you will have to either know their IDs, or they will have to have a common major version number.

Get the sample code from the download site here: [Apple Download Site](https://developer.apple.com/downloads/index.action).

Comment: Hi Rob,I got the videos.please let me know the sample code source.

Comment: Rob,Is there any function are class to get how many devices/UUIDs/Device names at least are available with in your range using iBeacons?.Please let me know the solution.

Comment: I already gave you the solution: all your devices have to have UDIDs that consist of 'major' and 'minor' parts. You want all your devices to have the same major ID and each must have a unique minor ID. Then you can ask for all devices with the given major key and it will show you all of them.

Comment: Rob,Sorry for interruption,please let me know  Is there any way to set the major and minor values.

Comment: Of course there is. Dude setup the example. It lets you make one device the beacon and the other the finder of the beacon. The code shows that you have total control over the UDID the beacon uses. You could easily change that code to look for 2 devices that differ only on minor version numbers.

Comment: if I had testing with two devices the major and Minor values are changing at every run.

Comment: Is there any way to change the Major and minor Id values programatically?Please let me know.

Comment: Laxmi, yes there is. When you create a beacon you specify the UUID, major and minor value to use for transmitting. Similarly, when you set up your app as a beacon receiver, you can specify just a UUID, a UUID and major value, or a UUID, major, and minor value. If you only specify a UUID, any beacon with that UUID will be treated as part of the region you're monitoring. IF you specify UUID and major, any beacon with that UUID and major will generate beacon notices. If specify all 3 parameters, they all must match.

Answer (score 0):

Here is a useful tutorial for learning how to turn your iPhone into a beacon: http://www.captechconsulting.com/blog/christopher-mann/ios-7-tutorial-series-core-location-beacons

Please note that you will need at least two devices to test this. I hope this helps.